# Problem in editing app.js while creating react app. When I am editing app.js after saving it then it automaticaly change its syntax

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio

Visual studio Code error while creating react app.
When I am editing the code in app.js file while creating react app, while saving it automatically comes to its position as shown in image. I have written this in code:

```
function app(){ <p> </p>}
```

but when I save, it automatically changes the layout to

```
function app(){< p> </p>}
```

I am learning this VS Code react app and I don't know what to do in this (image is also mentioned below). In a image same thing is mentioned after I save this file all the syntax is change:

[image]

Comment: I think that i done something wrong in setting , I am the beginner please someone help me out in this .

Comment: Have you installed any extensions?

Comment: YES, i installed JS-CSS-HTML Formatter  to run javascript file

Comment: What is the trouble, is it adding a newline in the `</p>` tag?